How to determine if a set is a sumset
Let $G$ be a commutative group (assume whatever you want on $G$ if needed. I am mainly interested in $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).
Let $k$ be a fixed integer.
Let $(a_1, \dots, a_{k^2})$ be a list of $k^2$ elements of $G$.
I am interested in the following problem:
Determine if there exist:

$(x_1, \dots, x_{k})$ a list of $k$ elements of $G$.
$(y_1, \dots, y_{k})$ a list of $k$ elements of $G$.
a bijection $\sigma: [1,k] \times [1,k] \rightarrow [1,k^2]$.
such that: for all $i,j=1 \dots k$, one has $x_i + y_j = a_{\sigma(i, j)}$.

My question is: has this problem been studied, and what do we know about it?
For example, I would like to know if this problem is NP-complete, or if there is an algorithm to solve the problem.
There is a similar question here,
but it was asked a long time ago and didn't catch much attention.

This is a variant of so-called turnpike / beltway reconstruction problems. In the case of $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ it can be solved via cyclotomic factorization by noticing that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k^2} z^{a_i} \equiv \big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} z^{x_i}\big)\cdot \big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} z^{y_i}\big)\pmod{z^n-1}.$$
Alternatively, solution can be based on spectral convolution - by noticing that pairwise differences of $x$'s as well as pairwise differences of $y$'s must have large multiplicities (at least $k$ each) in the multiset of pairwise differences of $a$'s.
